# AS3: Apply Mask to Multiple MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two MovieClips onscreen, and I want to apply the same mask to both. I set the the masks using

```
mc1.mask = mymask;
mc2.mask = mymask;
```

Only mc2 receives the mask. How can I set the same mask for two different MovieClips without having to resort to putting them both in a single MovieClip?

Comment: The ideal solution for my problem would involve cloning the mask. However, there is no duplicateMovieClip function in AS3 and I am hard-pressed in finding an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the mask a class and use instances of this class to mask each movie clip.

Your class could have set properties or if needs be you could pass parameters in the constructor for more flexibility...

```
var mask1:MyMask = new MyMask();
var mask2:MyMask = new MyMask();

mc1.mask = mask1;
mc2.mask = mask2;
```

Comment: My masks reside on the stage with no class definitions. All I can work with is an instance name. I am hoping to find a solution without having to make too many changes as there are many masks in my flash file.

Comment: Following your other comment, it should be possible to make a copy of the mask. The BitmapData class has a [clone method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#clone()) although I doubt this would be less work than making the mask a class!

Comment: Now that I think of it, you're right. I should be able to use Object(mask1).constructor to get the mask's class and work from there.

Answer (score 5):

if you are attempting to apply the same mask on both of your two sprites you can set the 2 sprite objects as children of a display object container and assign the mask to the container.

Comment: Both of the sprites are already on the stage. I tried to add them to a MovieClip container using addChild and then masking it, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I need a solution that does not involve removing the sprites from the stage (and adding them to another container).